# Spacing Labels and Buttons in Java

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, gridbaglayout

I'm still brushing up on the old Java GUI and ran into sort of a stump. It's just that the whole GUI thing is still fresh and I've only used FlowLayout() and I guess what I'm looking for cannot be done with it. This isn't for homework or anything, just something I am working on. Anyways, my problem:

Basically, I want it to look like this

```
Welcome!
Today's Date is: 
(space)
(space)
Exit button
```

My problem is I don't know enough of any of the layouts to get this done. I've been reading and messing with `GridBagLayout` and I can't get it to do anything and I've tried another way and the button was as big as the dang program. Anyways, here is the code that I have, even though it shouldn't really matter.

```
private void welcomeTab(){
    welcomePanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    String currentTime = SimpleDateFormat.getInstance().format(
    Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    final JLabel welcomeLabel = new JLabel("Welcome!", JLabel.CENTER);
    final JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel ("Today's date is: " + currentTime, JLabel.CENTER);
    welcomePanel.add(welcomeLabel);
    welcomePanel.add(dateLabel);
    welcomePanel.add(createExitButton());
}
```

Thank you. I've been reading so much and it seems all of the examples are for creating panes with all buttons and it's driving me insane.

Comment: you could use absolute layout and place your components pretty much wherever you want them. http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

Comment: @Bartzilla: *"..place your components pretty much wherever you want them."*   -1  The real trick is placing them where they **need** to be.  Once you figure the logic behind that, you might as well express it in a custom layout manager.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

[image: Welcome Panel]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class WelcomeLayout {

    private JPanel welcomePanel;

    WelcomeLayout() {
        welcomeTab();
        welcomePanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("The Welcome Panel"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, welcomePanel);
    }

    private void welcomeTab() {
        welcomePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0,1,1,1));
        String currentTime = SimpleDateFormat.getInstance().format(
        Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        final JLabel welcomeLabel = new JLabel("Welcome!", JLabel.CENTER);
        final JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel ("Today's date is: " + currentTime, JLabel.CENTER);
        welcomePanel.add(welcomeLabel);
        welcomePanel.add(dateLabel);

        // one (kludgy) way to addd space.
        welcomePanel.add(new JLabel(""));
        welcomePanel.add(new JLabel(""));

        welcomePanel.add( createExitButton() );
    }

    private JComponent createExitButton() {
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
        // the FlowLayout is to center the JButton;
        JPanel exitPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        exitPanel.add(exit);
        return exitPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                WelcomeLayout wl = new WelcomeLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

Using a `BoxLayout` as suggested by Talha Ahmed Khan/Zéychin

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

class WelcomeBoxLayout {

    private JPanel welcomePanel;

    WelcomeBoxLayout() {
        welcomeTab();
        welcomePanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder("The Welcome Panel"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, welcomePanel);
    }

    private void welcomeTab() {
        welcomePanel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(welcomePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        welcomePanel.setLayout(layout);
        String currentTime = SimpleDateFormat.getInstance().format(
        Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        final JLabel welcomeLabel = new JLabel("Welcome!", JLabel.CENTER);
        final JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel ("Today's date is: " + currentTime, JLabel.CENTER);
        welcomePanel.add(welcomeLabel);
        welcomePanel.add(dateLabel);

        welcomePanel.add( Box.createVerticalStrut(20) );

        welcomePanel.add( new JButton("Exit") );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                WelcomeBoxLayout wl = new WelcomeBoxLayout();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try addming a `Box.createHorizontalStrut(i_width)`

```
welcomePanel.add(welcomeLabel);
welcomePanel.add( Box.createHorizontalStrut(10) );
welcomePanel.add(dateLabel);
welcomePanel.add( Box.createHorizontalStrut(10) );
welcomePanel.add(createExitButton());
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to use a vertical BoxLayout. I'm not sure what Talha Ahmed Khan had in mind, 
because horizontal struts enforce the amount of horizontal space between two elements.

This link should help:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html

and here's a direct link to the source for the first example on that page:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/layout/BoxLayoutDemoProject/src/layout/BoxLayoutDemo.java

Answer (score 1):

`GridBagLayout` at its best with [Netbeans 7.0](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NewAndNoteworthyNB70#GUI_Builder_-_New_GridBagLayout_Designer). Check that out, you will not regret.

**Suggestion:**

Sort your problem out by using the **Netbeans GridBagLayout Designer**, then go read the generated code to understand the fix.

**Disclaimer:**

Writing custom code can be very hairy. You need to familiarise yourself with that. It provides hooks to add custom code, in most of the places. But still I find it very cumbersome. You need to sort that on your own.

Comment: *"..You need to sort that on your own."*  Which of course, is best done without the 'help' of a powerful, automagic IDE.  Throwing an IDE at a layout problem is not a solution until you understand the layouts.

Comment: @Andrew: Sort that out by a tool, and go read the generated code.... another way. I myself hate magic and don't want to do things without actually knowing it. I don't mind your negative though.

Comment: I'd offer to reverse the down-vote if you worked the 'hate magic' sentence back into your answer (in some form).  The problem with that theory is that it was not me who down-voted your reply.  I felt a comment was enough.  Peace.

Comment: @Andrew: Tried my best. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: +1 This is one virtue of the NetBeans GUI editor: you can experiment with an unfamiliar layout. IMO, the custom layout controls for `GridBagLayout` make it _much_ easier to understand.